# call javascript infovis sunburst rotate function outside init

Tags: javascript, infovis

I would like to simulate the click of a sunburst node from a menu outside of the canvas so that the clicked node is rotated until its horizontal, which is what happens when a node is clicked on the canvas.

The function:

```
sb.rotate(node, method, opt)
```

see [rotate](https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Visualizations/Sunburst-js.html#Sunburst.rotate)

where node is the value of "ID" in the JSON array, method is either 'animate' or 'replot' and opt is the configuration object

This is the type of error I get when I execute

```
sb.rotate("mynode", 'animate', "opt");
```

> TypeError: node.getPos is not a function. (In
>   'node.getPos(opt.property || 'current')', 'node.getPos' is undefined)

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/belefu/edit?html,css,js,console,output/)

Comment: Please add a fully functional example of the issue you're experiencing. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please see jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsbin, you have to use

```
sb.rotate(sb.graph.getNode("Source/Core/Core.js"), animate? 'animate' : 
'replot', 
{
    duration: 1000,
    transition: $jit.Trans.Quart.easeInOut
});
```

Notice the `sb.graph.getNode("Source/Core/Core.js")`
See https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Docs/files/Graph/Graph-js.html#Graph.getNode

You also forgot to issue the click in the jsbin. Use

```
button.click();
```

for that. ;)

Comment: +50 on the way as soon as the time permits

Comment: No need to hurry. Happy to help. :)